# AJAX doesn't transfer data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i want to transfer data from one page to another. I got 2pages: hostSettings.php and test.php

ok, here s my test.php 
it includes a submit-button and the ajax/jquery-script

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var test = "Hallo Welt!";
          $.ajax({
            url: "hostSettings.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: { test : test },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log("data transmitted: " + response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
          }); 

        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <font size="4">Test-Site</font>
    <hr>
    <?php include ("menu.html");?><br><br>

    <form method="POST" action="hostSettings.php">
      <input id="button" value="TEST" type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

hostSettings.php:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <font size="4">Hosts speichern</font><hr>
    <?php include ("menu.html");?><br><br>
    <br><br><br>

    <p><center>
      <h3>Diese Seite befindet sich momentan im Aufbau..</h3>
      <form action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Zurück zum Index">
      </form>
    </p></center>

    <?php
      if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if(isset($_POST["test"])) {
          echo $_POST["test"];
       }
      }
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

why doesnt it transfer the data from test.php to hostSettings.php :(

Comment: try a `<button>` type instead of an input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`submit` event is not designed for submit buttons.

You need to fire it on forms.

Either you fire event of `submit` of `form` or on `click` of `button`.

Change this:

```
$('#button').on('submit', function(e) {
```

To:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
```

And

```
<input type="submit" value="Zurück zum Index">
```

To:

```
<input type="button" value="Zurück zum Index">
```

Comment: always love a well-explained answer ;-)

Comment: I'm just slowly getting to learn all that JS stuff lol. I'm a "serverside" kind of guy ;-) Kind of figured OP needed a button type, as per what I left them in a comment up there.

Comment: Yes, @Fred-ii-, you have pointed out problem correctly in your comment.

Comment: Glad to have been of help :-) I don't post answers in JS related stuff (yet) because I don't know them enough. You covered all the bases.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I did that. Now it doesnt send me on "hostSettings.php" anymore. But i get an response at the log: the whole target-HTML. Here s a photo of the console-log: http://tinyurl.com/o8wvtnm

Comment: AJAX will return whatever printed on backend page. So, print only the required stuff, not whole HTML. It is working now.

Comment: @Chpo7234 I don't know why you're using `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )` in your second file. If you want to transfer data from page 1 to page 2, I think you're going about it the wrong way. Plus, why all those other forms as per your image?

Comment: Ops, sorry. I removed the server-command. Yes, i want to transfer data from test.php to hostSettings.php. Those other forms are a menu to navigate between different pages. But only the weirdo "xasdasd"-named button shall transfer the data..

Comment: @Chpo7234, if my answer worked for you, please mark it as solution so that other SO users can gain.

Answer (score 2):

you are doing an on submit on a button the on submit should be on the form. put an id to the form and tyr you same code and as Fred said use the button tag instead. You can also try the on('click') if you wish to use the button, and it will look much simpler too.

example 1. asuming you marked form with an id

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var test = "Hallo Welt!";
          $.ajax({
            url: "hostSettings.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: { test : test },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log("data transmitted: " + response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
          }); 

        });
      });
```

Example 2 :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var test = "Hallo Welt!";
          $.ajax({
            url: "hostSettings.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: { test : test },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log("data transmitted: " + response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
          }); 

        });
      });
```